# Use comparison test to find if the series $\frac{\sin n \cos n}{15^n}$ diverges/converges

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series

$$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{\sin n \cos n}{15^n}$$

Since it's a problem that involves trigonometric functions do we use the $A_n$ and $B_n$? Or is there a different approach?

Comment: The absolute value of the top is $\le 1$.

Comment: ^ I think you meant $\le \frac{1}{2} $ since $ \sin n \cos n = \frac{1}{2} \sin 2n$

Comment: Sure, it is $\le 1/2$. Thus in particular it is $\le 1$.

Comment: $\displaystyle\sin n\,\cos n=\frac{\sin2n}2\qquad,\qquad\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{\sin(nx)}{a^n}=\frac{a\sin x}{a^2-2a\cos x+1}\quad$

Answer (score 3):

We show that 
$$\sum_1^\infty \left|\frac{\sin n\cos n}{15^n}\right|\tag{1}$$
converges. That means that the series we were given *converges absolutely*, and hence converges.

Note that $|\sin n\cos n|\le 1$. It follows that
$$\left|\frac{\sin n\cos n}{15^n}\right|\le \frac{1}{15^n}.$$
The series $\sum_1^\infty \frac{1}{15^n}$ is a convergent geometric series. So by Comparison, the series (1) converges, and therefore our series does.

Comment: (+1) In fact, we can compute the sum
$$
\begin{align}
\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{\sin(n)\cos(n)}{15^n}
&=\frac1{4i}\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{e^{i2n}-e^{-i2n}}{15^n}\\
&=\frac1{4i}\left(\frac{\frac{e^{2i}}{15}}{1-\frac{e^{2i}}{15}}-\frac{\frac{e^{-2i}}{15}}{1-\frac{e^{-2i}}{15}}\right)\\
&=\frac{15\sin(2)}{452-60\cos(2)}
\end{align}
$$ I see that Lucian gave the general formula in a comment to the question.